# can we have a pop up without the use of alert or windows.alert

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo, popup

ideally when i a click a action item in my table it shows "show message" on clicking on to it i need a popup without the use of window.alert or alert instead show a pop up based on my website design

```
function showFailedWarning(){
    dijit.byId('validationsForm').clearMessages();
    dijit.byId('validationsForm').popup(alert("Upload Correct File "));
}
```

Comment: Try jQuery UI Dialog: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

Comment: Even leaner and cleaner is NOTY: http://needim.github.io/noty/

Comment: @DevlshOne Both still require `jQuery` or an additionnal library to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Method #1 - Pure JavaScript

You can build your own pop-up with whatever design you want. Either *hardcode* the elements in HTML and set `display:none` to the container in CSS, or dynamically append the container.

**Note:** [Why I used `innerHTML` in place of `appendChild()`](http://jsperf.com/html-innerhtml-vs-appendchild).

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/XFace/)

### HTML

```
<button id="error">Click for error</button>
```

### JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('error').onclick = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    /*Creating and appending the element */

    var element = '<div id="overlay" style="opacity:0"><div id="container">';
    element += "<h1>Title</h1><p>Message</p>";
    element += "</div></div>";
    document.body.innerHTML += (element);
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = "block";

    /* FadeIn animation, just for the sake of it */
    var fadeIn = setInterval(function () {
        if (document.getElementById('overlay').style.opacity > 0.98) clearInterval(fadeIn);
        var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
        overlay.style.opacity = parseFloat(overlay.style.opacity, 10) + 0.05;
        console.log(parseFloat(overlay.style.opacity, 10));

    }, 50);
};
```

### CSS

```
#overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity:0;
    display:none;
}
#container {
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
    width: 400px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:#111;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:4px;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

---

---

---

## Method #2 - Third-party libraries

You can use libraries such as `jQuery UI` to achieve what you want:

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/XFace/2/)

### HTML

```
<button id="error">Click for error</button>
```

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$('#error').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('<div id="container"><h1>Error</h1><p>Message</p></div>').dialog({
        title: "Error"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you this question has the dojo tag and you have dijit code in your example, I would suggest using `dijit.Dialog` to do this.

I put together a quick example on [jsfiddle demonstrating it](http://jsfiddle.net/jrkeller/NkhSS/).

```
require(['dijit/Dialog', 'dijit/form/Button'], function (Dialog, Button) {
    //create a new button (doesn't matter if it is programmatically or not)
    var button = new Button({
        label: 'Validate',
        type: 'button'
    });
    button.placeAt(dojo.body());
    button.on('click', function () {
        //instantiate the dialog with our error message and content
        var dialog = new Dialog({
            title:'Error Message title',
            content: '<div>Something is invalid!</div>',
            style:'min-width:300px;'
        });
        //show the error message
        dialog.show();
    });


});
```

The [dojo docs for dijit/Dialog](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Dialog.html) should also be helpful to look at.